# Integral derivative calculation

Tags: integration, derivatives

$$\int_0^y e^{-t^2} dt + \int_0^{x^2} \sin^2(t) dt = 0$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \ ?$$
I've been learning Integrals and came across this problem, would love a detailed explanation on how to solve this.

Comment: It's not $u$ it is $x$ I have a bad hand writing.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Patrick really appreciated <3

Comment: If you search in Google *14.1 Second fundamental theorem of calculus*, the first entry is for simple examples from a page of MIT. Then you need read and understand these, with your summands. When you take the derivative of $y=y(x)$ you need write $y'=y'(x)$. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate with respect to $x$ using the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

$$e^{-y^2} \dfrac{dy}{dx} + 2x\sin^2(x^2) = 0$$

(Though it is Christmas Eve, a day on which I am more than usually liable to make algebraic errors.)

Comment: Should that be $e^{-y^2} \dfrac{dy}{dx} + 2x \cdot \sin^2(x^2) = 0$?

Comment: Thanks Rohan and JimmyK4542!

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating the integral we have using [Leibnitz rule like this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139183/differentiating-definite-integral), we get, $$e^{-y^2} \frac{dy}{dt} - 0 + 2x\frac{dx}{dt} \sin^2 x^2 - 0 = 0$$ Thus on rearranging, we have, $$e^{-y^2} \frac{dy}{dt} = -2x\frac{dx}{dt} \sin^{2}x^2 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{-2x\sin^{2} x^2}{e^{-y^2}}$$ Hope it helps.