# Differentiating an integral general result

Tags: integration

I saw a result a while ago which stated if $f(Y) = \int^{Y} g(t)dt$, then $f'(Y) = g(Y)$, where we differentiate with respect to Y. I'm unable to find any sources on this result (in particular, what it is called). I believe it is used in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139183/differentiating-definite-integral)

What is the name of this result?

Comment: You're missing hypotheses, but this is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is the first part of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). Let $f$ be a function that is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$. Then, let $F:[a,b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$$
F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt
$$
The fundamental theorem of calculus states that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and
$$
F'(x)=f(x)
$$
for all $x$ in $(a,b)$. This result can be summarised as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt = f(x) \, .
$$
Integrating a function, followed by differentiating it, gets you back where you started. Note that *integrating* refers to finding the area under the curve. Really, that's what an integral *is*. The fact that functions of the form
$$
\int f(x) \, dx
$$
are often called 'indefinite integrals' is a result of the fundamental theorem of calculus, since
$$
\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt = \int f(x) \, dx \, .
$$